# How to put files with Talend respecting directory structures

Tags: talend

I'm trying to ftp files from a directory containing subdirectories and I'd like the directory structure/hierarchy to be respected on the server.

The job looks like this :
[image]

With the various components set like this :
[image: tFileListSettings]

[image: tIterateToFlowSettings]

[image: ftpPutSettings]

and I've got a NullPointer Exception when accessing the `row1.localPath` variable (even if when tLogRow I see the right information I need).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could link the tFileList directly to the tFTPPut component(iterate link), using tFileList_1_CURRENT_FILEPATH as the local directory in tFTPPut.